# Is it a reasonable task to automatically convert ANTLR grammars to my own format?

Tags: programming-languages, parsing, syntax, grammar

I was working on my own parser generator tool in Clojure and then I realised I want to test it with some real programming languages.
I can find [a lot of existing language grammars only in antlr v4 format](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4).

That means if I can automatically translate antlr grammars to my own format, I can get them all. Is that a reasonable task(because I haven't noticed other parser generators with antlr-converters, so there must be something hard)

Comment: Be wary of those grammars. Not all of them are very good. If I could do it all over again, I'd build my own grammar based on the language spec so that I knew it was correct.

Comment: That would be the best thing, but I wanted to support at least 5-6 of the most used languages(I want to do some additional syntax-based reserach on them, so I'd love to parse them and play with their ast-s in the same language/format). That's why I hoped for a smartass semi-automated thing

Comment: It shouldn't be too terribly awful to mechanically transform any of those grammars into another format, but it may not matter if they're not correct to begin with. Like any open source anything, you should verify that it is correct before using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is translating [ANTLR](http://antlr.org) grammars to my own format a reasonable task?

That depends on your definition of reasonable. If you mean "achievable" or "worthwhile given the time and effort required", that is only something you can answer. Presumably, if you have written your own parser, this should not be too difficult.

If you mean "legal" (e.g. violating copyrights or patents), that depends on the individual or organization that created the ANTLR grammar. Some grammars may be licensed or have other legal protections. For example, a grammar licensed under [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) may require any works based on this (such as your own grammars or code generated to parse it) to also be licensed under GPL. If in doubt, talk to a legal professional or the person or organization that created or is responsible for the grammar.

If you mean "looked down upon", "cutting corners" or "being lazy", all grammars have been derived from something. Once you have written a few grammars, there are diminishing returns for doing everything from scratch. I would talk to other members of the parser/lexer community and see what they do.

If you mean "best practice", as @RubberDuck has said, some published grammars may have errors or omissions. Carefully check any third party grammars before copying them. You may want to derive your own then use other grammars as a reference or test data.

Comment: Please make it more clear that it depends on the license of the grammar, not Antlr's. For instance, any code generated from a GPL licensed grammar has to be licensed GPL as well. The grammar license has a huge impact on how you can license your project in some cases.

Comment: @RubberDuck Good call. The answer is updated as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Almost what I meant. It's not just the grammar itself that has licensing implications, [but the code generated from it as well](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1933/775) though. +1

Comment: @RubberDuck Another good point, one that I should have realized. Answer amended again.